# Capturing UserID and passing it along to stored procedure through button click

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an application where a logged-in user can sign up for certain events. Upon hitting the "Sign Up" button I call a stored procedure to add a record into the database so they will be added to that event. I capture information in text boxes and pass that to the stored procedure with Parameter.AddWithValue- But I am not sure how to get the userID passed to that SQL stored procedure so it can insert the correct record and the correct user will be added to the table indicating that userID is signed up.

(Note- I am validating the username and password upon login- I do not directly gather the userID fro the user logging in. But the "Validate_User" procedure checks the username and PW against the Users table in the DB upon logging in- so it is looking at the record with the userID as the primary key. I'm just not sure how to "grab" that to use later

I am exploring using global variable or session to store a user id after logging in.

My question is- where would this code go? I am very new to coding and am a bit confused on where I would write the session_ID or declare the global variable. Would it be on the login page as part of the login control? The landing page they get to after logging in?

Also, I a not sure how to call the session or variable in other pages. Can I just go into the .aspx.vb file for that page and call it? Or just start using it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Let me know if you need any code snippets to further troubleshoot

Below is the login.aspx.vb that validates the user and allows login...

```
Partial Class login
 Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub ValidateUser(sender As Object, e As AuthenticateEventArgs)      Handles Login1.Authenticate
    Dim userID As Integer = 0
    Dim roles As String = String.Empty
    Session("roles") = Nothing
    Using con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BandDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Validate_User")
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Login1.UserName)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Login1.Password)
            cmd.Connection = con
            con.Open()
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If reader.Read() Then
                userID = Convert.ToInt32(reader("UserId"))
                roles = reader("RoleName").ToString()
                Session("roles") = roles
            End If

            con.Close()
        End Using
        Select Case userID
            Case 1
                Login1.FailureText = "Username and/or password is incorrect."
                Exit Select
            Case 2
                Login1.FailureText = "Account has not been activated."
                Exit Select
            Case Else
                Dim ticket As New FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, Login1.UserName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2880), Login1.RememberMeSet, roles,
             FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath)
                Dim hash As String = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket)
                Dim cookie As New HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hash)
                If ticket.IsPersistent Then
                    cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration
                End If
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)
                Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet))
                Exit Select
        End Select
    End Using
End Sub
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
        If Me.Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
            Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx")
        Else
            Session.Abandon()
            Session.Clear()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

This code is form the sign up button (that the logged in user clicks to be added.) This is where I need the userID. Currently I have it rigged with a UserID text boc that I manually enter the correct userID for by checking the DB. This is a workaround to test all the other things happening...

```
Partial Class Students_studentsignup
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Private Function GetUserID(username As String)
    Dim userID As Integer

    'Code here to quesry database and get userID based on logged in user's username
    Using con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BandDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim sqlquery1 As New SqlCommand("select UserID from Users where username = ")

    End Using

    Return userID
 End Function




Protected Sub btnSignUp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSignUp.Click
    Dim UserID As Integer = GetUserID(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)
    Dim audition_Id As Integer = 0

    Using con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BandDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Insert_Student_Audition")
            Using sda As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter()
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@student_firstname", txtStudentFirstName.Text.Trim())
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@student_lastname", txtStudentLastName.Text.Trim())
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KSUID", txtKSUID.Text.Trim())
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserID)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@audition_ID", txtAuditionID.Text.Trim())
                cmd.Connection = con
                con.Open()
                UserID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
                con.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
        Dim message As String = String.Empty
        Select Case UserID
            Case = 1
                message = "User is already added to this audition."
                Exit Select
            Case Else
                message = "Congratulations! You are now signed up for this audition. " + audition_Id.ToString()

                Exit Select
        End Select
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript([GetType](), "alert", (Convert.ToString("alert('") & message) + "');", True)
    End Using


End Sub
```

End Class

Here is the Users table...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
[UserID]        INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Username]      NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Password]      NVARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
[Email]         NVARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
[CreatedDate]   DATETIME      NOT NULL,
[LastLoginDate] DATETIME      NULL,
[RoleID]        NCHAR (10)    DEFAULT ((3)) NULL,
[Phone]         NVARCHAR (30) NULL,
[FirstName]     NVARCHAR (30) NULL,
[LastName]      NVARCHAR (30) NULL,
[FullName]      AS            (([FirstName]+'')+[LastName]),
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserID] ASC)
```

);

I am almost able to do this. I have proven I can get the correct userName by capturing and displaying it in a label `(Dim user_Name As String = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)`. I am now using that to get the userId as seen below...

```
  Private Function GetUserID(username As String) As Integer

        Dim userId As Integer
        Dim user_Name As String = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
        Using con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BandDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
            Dim sqlquery1 As New SqlCommand("select UserID from Users where username = user_Name")
        End Using

        Return userId

    End Function
    Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim audition_Id As Integer = Request.QueryString("audition_ID")

        Dim userID As Integer = GetUserID(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)

        lblAuditionNum.Text = userID
    End Sub
```

However- it only displays "0".

I am thinking this issue is in my SQL query..

```
 Using con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BandDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
                Dim sqlquery1 As New SqlCommand("select UserID from Users where username = user_Name")
            End Using

            Return userId
```

But I am not sure how to test it

Comment: Do not use a global variable in an asp.net application.  It's not thread-safe and multiple users hitting your application at the same time will cause you much grief.  Session state would be a better choice.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

It is Username and password. 

It is a very simple login. Hitting the "register" button calls a "Insert_User" stored procedure that checks that the info is valid, then adds the username, and password to the Users table. Afterwards you go to the login page and enter the username and password. Hitting login calls a "validate_User" stored procedure that checks the username and password provided.

The login does work. (although i'm having web.config issues directing the user to the appropriate directory based on the roleID- but that's another story._)

Comment: Thanks dwilliss! 
Would you know the best way to tackle this? Should i initiate the session on the login page so as the "Validate_User" procedure runs it stores the userID at that point? 

I also need to look into calling variables in that session on other pages (specifically filtering grid views and other data sets based on the currently logged in userID)

Comment: I am doing some research on Sessions and it makes sense to me that you can grab them, declare and store them- however most emaples I see are for username and grab that from the username textbox on the login page.
I don't have a userID text boc- so I have no way of DIRECTLY getting this. 

Session("FirstName") = FirstNameTextBox.Text
Session("LastName") = LastNameTextBox.Text

Answer (score 0):

I would look at creating a function which returns the userId in your `Students_studentsignup` class (assuming you don't have a student class anywhere) as follows

```
Private Function GetUserID(userName As String) As Integer

    Dim userId As Integer

    Using con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\BandDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim comm As New SqlCommand("select UserID from Users where username = userName", con)
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("userName", userName)
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        con.Open()

        Try
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader = comm.ExecuteReader()

            If reader.HasRows Then
                While (reader.Read)
                    userId = reader.GetInt32(0)
                End While
                reader.Close()
                Return userId
            Else
                'no user found
                Return -1
            End If
        Catch e As Exception
            Throw New Exception("An exception has occurred: " + e.Message)
        Finally
            con.Close()
        End Try

    End Using

End Function
```

You can get the logged in user using

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

You would then call the function, passing the logged in user as the parameter as follows

```
Protected Sub btnSignUp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSignUp.Click
    Dim audition_Id As Integer = 0
    Dim userID as Integer = GetUserID(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the suggestion!

Would this work for UserID and int? 

I guess I could filter the datasets based on username, but I assumed userID (being the primary key on the users table) would be the best way to do it

Comment: It might be worth adding some code to your question as it is quite hard to follow what is going on and means some of what I have written above is vague

Comment: @Searle1986 - gotcha, I will look at that. 

and i will be adding code here shortly to give a better idea! Thanks for the responses

Comment: Just added login.aspx.vb to the original question

Comment: @derloopkat - I am not using Windows authentication. Just a very simple internal login mechanism.

Comment: Ok, you can't get the user id in your valudate_user method as it is an event handler and returns nothing. It is likely you will need to get the userId in the code where you are calling your stored procedure which adds the user to the event. Again. unfortunately we can't see the code for that

Comment: thanks for the input. The code I posed in the orginal question is from the login.aspx.vb page- and that is the code where i'm calling Validate_User.....................

Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Validate_User")
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure......................................

I can post the actual Validate_User procedure- or any other code you'd need to seee to get a better idea of what's going on

Comment: Where is the code that is doing this " I call a stored procedure to add a record into the database so they will be added to that event. "

Comment: Ahhh- so you mean the code that adds the logged in user to the event? So this is after all the login happens (Currently I have it rigged with a "userID" text box that I enter the userID to (I just look at the DB to get the one i'm logged in as). Obviously this isn't a permanent solution- i've done that just to test everything else works. 

I can add that code too

Comment: Yes, that code needs to be visible. If I were you, I'd create a function which accepts a string username parameter and returns the userID (which would have to uery the database. I would call that function before you call your stored procedure that adds the user to the event

Comment: just added that code! 

And do you have any examples or instructions on how i'd go about doing that?

Comment: also i'm abit confused on how the query would work. 

I'm selecting userID, but based on what? Do a Session to store the username and then have my function do a 
"Select userId FROM users WHERE username = @sessionUsernamevariable" ?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the structure of your users table but I have made a guess in the updated answer

Comment: Just uploaded the users table. 
I think I understand what you mean now. I created the function and now am just working on the SQL query syntax.
I am decent at pure SQL queries- so I amwondering if I could just make one to run the query and call that in VB? 
I am new to VB and my only experience with these type of DB connections is calling store dprocedures

Comment: just updated my Submit button code where I am creating the GetUserID function

Comment: The only difference between calling a stored procedure and a regular SQL query is the command type property should be "text" rather than "stored procedure'

Comment: I am having some trouble with the SQL query. Could I declare 'tempusername' as a variable and set it equal to  (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name) and then in my SQL query do "WHERE username =tempusername" ?


Also, how is this the UserID, doesn't this return the username? 

 Dim userID as Integer = GetUserID(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)


Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Your query should return the userid for the given username SELECT UserID FROM Users WHERE Username =

Comment: So no condition is needed for the WHERE clause? Just "WHERE userName = "

Comment: Where username = username. 

You would then have to create a parameter called username using the AddWithValue method like you did before

Comment: I think I almost have it. I was able to get the username but my SQL query isn't working to convert that to the userID. I edited the bottom of my orignal questions

Comment: This is SO close to working. I've tested and found that it is actually just returning the highest UserID in the Users table with the SQL query.I can add the correct username with(userName= System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name) but the UserID added doesn't correspond to it. I think it is just running "Select userID from Users". I tried enclosing the userName in single quotes (where username = 'username') but that just returns -1

I'm thinking I have to format the query so that it is passed to SQL with the username variable enclosed like a string in a typical SQL query @Searle1986